# Conditional th:action in spring

Tags: java, spring, forms, thymeleaf

I have a `form` to modify an object. This object can be used in two pages, with the same values.

I would like to have two buttons and depending on the button submited send to one page or another.

Right now my code is something like this:

```
<!-- Make my action dinamically depending on button submitted -->
<form action="#" th:action="@{/action}" th:object="${myObject}"
      method="post">
  <input type="submit" name="new" value="new"/>
  <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit"/>
</form>
```

`th:action` should be dynamic.

I have created method in my controller so depending on the action I can deal with it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/new", "/edit"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handlePost(@RequestParam String action, @ModelAttribute MyObject myObject) {

    if (action.equals("new")) {
        //Make some stuff
        return "new";

    } else if (action.equals("edit")) {
        //Make some stuff
        return "edit";
    }

    return "index";
}
```

In Thymeleaf docs I have seen something similar but I'm not be able to deal with it.

**UPDATE 1**

My object is a matrix with N columns rendered in my page. If everything is ok I edit its values, but I can add new columns using **new** action.

I want two buttons and depending which of them go to new or go to edit.
The object always exist.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I did this in following way:

In controller:

```
modelAndView.addObject("action", "Save");
```

In your template:

```
th:action="${action} == 'Save' ? @{/manageCategory/addEditCategory/addCategory} : @{/manageCategory/addEditCategory/editCategory}" th:object="${addCategoryDTO}" method="POST"

<button th:text="${action == 'Edit'} ? 'Edit' : 'Save'"  id="btnsubmit"  class="btn blue okMark" type="submit" ></button>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it'll be easier doing this using javascript.

```js
let form = document.forms[0]; // or replace with an identifier for the form


Array.from(form.getElementsByTagName('input')).filter(e => e.type === 'submit').forEach(btn => 
  btn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    form.setAttribute('action', '/' + e.target.name);
    console.log(form.getAttribute('action'));
    form.submit();
  })
 );
```

```html
  <form action="#" th:action="@{/action}"  th:object="${myObject}"
            method="post">
            <input type="submit" name="new" value="new" />
            <input type="submit" name="edit" value="edit" />
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

at least in newer versions of Thymeleaf, according to [standard URL syntax](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html), one can use ${} expressions inside @{} expressions, so what worked for me, is this:

```
...
th:action="@{${myObject != null && !maybesomethingelse ? '/edit' : '/new'}}" 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you want to post to `/new` when you don't have an existing object and to `/edit`when you do.

Your action should be something like

`th:action="${myObject != null ? '/edit' : '/new'}`

It's not the cleanest code ever since you're inserting logic in your template and you'd probably be better off by setting the action value as a ModelView property in the controller that renders the form, but I think it may work this way.

Besides, you should also consider splitting your form handler in two separate methods, one mapped to `/new` and one mapped to `/edit`, possibly factoring out any code in common, instead of checking the value of `action`.

Comment: But that will not result in URL which should contain context path.

Comment: If you need to use `@{/action}` to keep the context path, then your only solution is to populate the action variable in the controller that renders the form.

Comment: I think that this should work: `th:action="@{myObject != null ? '/edit' : '/new'}`

Comment: Not sure the syntax is correct, it may be `@{${myObject != null ? '/edit' : '/new'}}`

Comment: No, myObject exist always, it represent a matrix and new is for add a NEW column (I didn't explain it correctly). So, depending on submited button I add a new column or edit the existing columns. That's the idea, maybe there is another way to do it. thxs